# How do I remove elements of PixelArray

Tags: python, pygame

In the code

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((900,900))
img0 = pygame.image.load("assets/cat.jpg")

run = True
while run:
    pygame.display.flip()
    window.fill((255,255,255))

    window.blit(img0, (0,0))
    img0PA = pygame.PixelArray(img0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                for c in range(len(img0PA)):
                    if c%2:
                        img0PA[c].pop()
                    else:
                        for r in range(len(img0PA[c])):
                            if r%2:
                                img0PA[c,r].pop()

    window.blit(img0PA.make_surface(), (len(img0PA),0))
    img0PA.close()

pygame.quit()
```

I'm trying to grab the PixelArray of img0 and delete every odd row and column. Using the pop command The compiler prompts.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

How can I remove every odd row and column using the PixelArray module?

Answer (score 1):

The operation

```py
img0PA[c,r].pop()
```

does not make any sense.

`img0PA` as on object of the class [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html). A pixel array can be indexed by *`[column, row]`*, thus `img0PA[c,r]` returns a single pixel as an integral value. The method `.pop` is not defined on an `int`.

A [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) is used to address and manipulate the pixels of a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). It is not possible to change the size of the Surface by deleting rows and columns form the pixel array.

If you want to create a Surface with a different size, the you have to create a new [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object.
You can use [`pygame.PixelArray`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pixelarray.html) to copy single pixels form one Surface to the other Surface.

---

If you want to scale a `Surface`, then I recommend to use [`pygame.transform.scale()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.scale) or [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale). e.g:

```py
window.blit(img0, (0,0))
img0Scaled = pygame.transform.scale(img0, (0.5, 0.5))
window.blit(img0Scaled, (img0Scaled.get_width(), 0))
```

Comment: Is there anyway i can manipulate the array so that i can remove certain parts of it

Comment: @gamersbeware No. You have to create an new `Surface` with a different size.